# Replace variables in jade without rendering to html

Tags: node.js, pug

I am using jade as a kind of markup language for a thermal printer. That means on the website i render a print preview to html, and i am sending the jade(with custom tags) directly  to the printer which interprets the tags for different text styles. 
It works pretty well but now i would like to use also locals in that template but render only the locals not to html.

That means

```
p #{name}
```

should become

```
p John Doe
```

instead of

```
<p>John Doe</p>
```

Is there a possibility to do this with some function in the jade package ? Or do i need to write that from scratch. I also want to use jade  "each" loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prefix it with a pipe symbol:

```
| p #{name}
```

Comment: Very good idea. This is working for me. Maybe the easiest way since its looks to me like, jade is merging the variables and doing the convertion to html in one step. So there's no way to do one thing without the other

Comment: @maggocnx Jade is pretty tailored towards generating HTML :)